# Git: 'Master cannot be resolved to branch' after merge

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

Every time I merge a branch back into my master branch, I can no longer push to origin. I get the message `fatal: master cannot be resolved to branch`

I made a simple test change:

- Created a new branch `git branch TestBranch`
- Made a change to TestBranch and commited
- Checked out back to master `git checkout Master`
- Merged TestBranch `git merge TestBranch`

The merge seems to have gone fine, but now when I use Git status the Master branch does not tell me that it is ahead of the origin. And when I try to push to origin Master I get the message above.

Does anybody know what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Could it be that you write Master instead of master? If the system is case sensitive they wouldn't match, and lower-case master is the default in most repositories.

Comment: It's true what they say about devils and details.

Comment: I also did the same mistake, misspelled the branch name. Thanks.

Comment: YES capitalization was indeed the problem thanks very much

Comment: @EthanParker, Buy how do I workaround it? My branch is in capitalization. I had misused the lower-case. But I changed back the name to capitalized, but still got the error.

Answer (score 1):

Another issue might be this with your workflow:

*Created a new branch `git branch TestBranch`*

With the command above, you **create** a branch, but **do not switch to it**.

I believe you should checkout manually by `git checkout TestBranch` **or** create the branch with checkout and create it by `git checkout -b TestBranch`.

Comment: And of course, the *Master* vs. *master* issue could be another problem as @Eivind pointed out.