# How to fix "cannot be resolved to branch" on git push?

Tags: git, github

When I do a `git status`, I get my branch:

```
$ git status
On branch OfflineLoading
```

When I tried to `git push`, I get:

```
$ git push origin OfflineLoading
fatal: OfflineLoading cannot be resolved to branch.
```

When I check the branches, it is not there:

```
$ git branch
   branch1
   branch2
   branch3
   branch4
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you create and changed your work to your new branch? This can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860362/git-master-cannot-be-resolved-to-branch-after-merge

Comment: I guess you might be doing some spelling mistake / case mistake. Ideally, it should make the remote branch if it doesn't exist or push to remote branch if it exists. Your command seems correct

Comment: I checked the spelling and it is right. Do I need to set upstream?

Comment: can you post the output of `git show-ref | grep -i OfflineLoading`

Comment: Is the local branch tracking the upstream one?

Comment: How did you create this branch `OfflineLoading`?  Specifically, *did you use `git checkout --orphan`?* If so, that's the problem: orphan branches aren't actually created until you commit something into them. If not, something is seriously wrong on your computer / in your repository.

Comment: Also please share what version of git, operating system, and if/what git GUI you're using.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I just bit the bullet and saved off my repo and cloned again. Then I overlayed files with my saved directory. Not elegant, but did the trick.

Comment: most of the time it changes the first letter with caps , you try by doing ``` git branch``` and search your branch and then checkout that branch and then do the ```git push```

Answer (score 39):

The common issue is case mistake. I got the same issue before. The better way to do it is to check what are the branch names:

```
$ git branch
  master
 *branch1
  Branch2
```

you can compare the branch on above, then push it with the name you got.

```
$ git push origin Branch2
```

or

```
$ git push origin branch1
```

Answer (score 11):

In addition to Kyle's answer,

In cases where you already have a branch name like "Bug**F**ix/item001" and pushed it to your repository, and then you created another branch with the name "Bug**f**ix/item002", you will still get the same error even if you try to push the branch with the correct casing.
I believe this is because of the "BugFix" folder being created already and future branches will use the same folder.

It is still a casing mistake but really misleading.

Comment: Correct answer. My solution is  renaming the old branches to something else, then renaming them back. It's caused by "git case sensitivity" problem.

Comment: exactly my case, the suggested workaround worked.

Answer (score 4):

My branch name was **feature/S212121_TestCase_review_Dashboard**

When I try to push code to this branch feature/S212121_TestCase_review_Dashboard by using following command:

```
git push origin feature/S212121_TestCase_review_Dashboard
fatal: feature/S212121_TestCase_review_Dashboard cannot be resolved to branch
```

Then I have renamed the my branch using following command:

```
git branch -m TestCase_review_CWLA_Dashboard
```

After that I have used following command to push the code:

```
git push --set-upstream origin TestCase_review_CWLA_Dashboard
```

This works for me I am able to push the code to branch.

Comment: This works for me thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this happens when you mistakenly checked out a wrong branch, do a commit on the same wrong branch and then do a push. On my case I had a branch called questionbank and made a mistake of checking out questionBank (note with capital 'B'), then I did a commit and git allowed it all up to a point when I wanted to do a push.

Solution was to checkout the correct branch (which on my case was "questionbank"), do some change on the code ( just for git to allow you to commit) then do a commit and then the push will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you have any capital letter in your branch name because the branch names are case sensitive. So go to .git-> refs-> heads then you can see your branches, remove the capital letter from your current branch name and that's it.

Comment: This is the actual answer

Answer (score 1):

It might be because you are not in the latest master branch.

For this you could check with terminal commands on the master branch:

```
git pull
```

or

```
git pull origin (master branch)
```

and checked your branch.

I created a new branch

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

and pushed to a new branch from the old branch that "has cannot be resolved" error using:

```
git push origin newbranch
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Checking out to a new branch and pushing it again works for me.
`git checkout -b 2020-08-05/OfflineLoading`
`git push`

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a small change and add my commit again then push and it worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution, but worked for me :

Checkout to different branch (let's say eg: 'branch2') & again checkout back to your feature branch and try to push to remote.