# git push with error [fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly]

Tags: git

My branch name is in capital, say, ABC.
I misused it in the lower-case, abc.

```
git check out abc
```

Even under the lower-case brach (abc), it still worked with rebase. After rebase, I started to push the code,

```
git push origin ABC -f
```

Got the error,

> fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Then I checked out the capital name branch, ABC. And still got the error when pushing it.

I found another post discussed it but no solution for my problem.
[Git: 'Master cannot be resolved to branch' after merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860362/git-master-cannot-be-resolved-to-branch-after-merge)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out.

Delete the false brach, abc.

```
git branch -d abc
```

Push the correct one,

```
git push origin ABC -f
```

> error: src refspec ABC does not match any.

Then checkout ABC again,

```
git checkout ABC
```

Then push it again,

```
git push origin ABC -f
```